# Multiple Ejabberd Node With Single Mysql

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

is it possible to have multiple ejabberd node that connect to one mysql and use the same database for all ejabberd node? is there any problem that will be occured?

Comment: yes, look at: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/clustering/

Comment: yes u can . You just need to have same ejabberd.yml in all nodes.

Comment: @ManiKandan Thanks Mani, this configuration(2 ejabberd 1 mysql) will not make any problem in the future won't it? I mean problem like db lock or anything else.

Comment: am not sure about that.